# How do I make a logic gate that takes 4 input and gives and output if only one is powered?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

How can I make a red_stone logic gate/gates that takes in 4 inputs but only gives an output when 1 of them is powered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being `X` is your output, and `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are your inputs,

```
X = ((A && !B && !C && !D) || (!A && B && !C && !D) || (!A && !B && C && !D) || (!A && !B && !C && D))
```

There are better methods, but this is one of the simplest to derive. `&&` is an `AND` gate, and `||` is an `OR` gate.
The brackets group simultaneous lines/operations.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as correct if it is correct.